# Slow searching OSX Server from Windows machines

Tags: windows, file-sharing, osx-server

Our graphics/media/photo files archived onto share points on Xserve.

Photographer's macs are to be replaced by Windows PCs.

Initial test with PC suggests that we can access share points and files and navigate to files, but are unable to search reliably -- Entering job number and searching archives is so slow as to be unusable.

Do we need to change a setting on Server Admin to improve the search speed?

Files are indexed in Spotlight and shared out over AFP and SMB.

In SMB setting - enabled oplocks, enabled strict locking.

OSX Server 10.6

Answer (score 1):

There is no cross-platform standard for keeping a fast search index up to date on a server.

OS X Server has a Spotlight server feature to allow OS X clients to do fast Spotlight searches of the server's files, but Windows doesn't have a native client for it, and Apple doesn't provide a Windows client for it.

There are third party products from companies like HELIOS that provide solutions to this problem.
Here's [HELIOS's solution](http://www.helios.de/web/EN/products/Spotlight-Search.html). If you do a bit of searching, you can probably find other third-party commercial solutions.